# 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_resolution.dart': Failed assertion: line 174 pos 15: 'assetName != null': is not true

Tags: firebase, image, flutter

I have a grid view to display the images however the images is store in my local which "assets/images/xxxx.png". I have only store the image name(assets/images/xxxx.png) into Firebase but not sure the way that I'm doing is right or wrong.

Have to mention they have no any wrong in "pubspec.yaml" file and the name of the images because I have manually display the images , however I would like to change the picture based on some condition so save the image to Firebase and retrieve it in grid view.

**Output from debug console**

From the output of the Firebase that retrieve have been get the name of the image which show as below but it's not showing up the images, should I save the image instead of the name of the image to Firebase as well if want to retrieve the image from Firebase? Or is there any way to save the name and once call the name of the image it will show up the image because it's already been declare in "assets/images/xxx.png" so I have no idea how to get the image to display. Either store the name of the image or image itself to Firebase and retrieve it out

```
"imageUrl":"assets/images/Materials-03.png"
```

This is the way how I retrieve all the data however have been printed all the data and it's coming this error so would it be problems of Image also not sure

**Display**

```
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final appProfileData = Provider.of<UserProfileLogic>(context);
        return GridView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          itemCount: appProfileData.appitems.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: appProfileData.appitems[i],
            child: AppGetFromLogic(),
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            //define how gridview been structure. E.g: Column
            crossAxisCount: 2, //how many column
            childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10, //spacing between column
            mainAxisSpacing: 10, //spacing of the row
          ),
        );
      }
```

**"AppGetFromLogic"**

```
 @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final appCalling = Provider.of<AppProfile>(context, listen: false);
        return Card(
          child: Hero(
            tag: appID,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: GridTile(
                footer: GridTileBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
                  title: Text(
                    appCalling.title,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Image.asset(
                  appCalling.appImage,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
```

Comment: How are you displaying the images?

Comment: I'm use Asset.Image(imageName) something like that to retrieve the image